# PyQGIS : QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV3 export Z dimension not working

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, export, geopackage

I am trying to make a plugin for QGIS using pyQGIS.
[image]

I would like to make a script that export the Z dimension (with offset) using this snippet:

```
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV3(
    vl,
    filename,
    QgsProject.instance().transformContext(),
    QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
)
```

But the Z dimension is NULL on QGIS after this export.

Note that when i just import it in QGIS as virtual layer (`QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vl)`), the $z dimension is NOT giving NULL.

So I conclude the export in GPKG erase the Z value. To patch this i have added the following option:

```
options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
options.includeZ = True
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV3(
    vl,
    filename,
    QgsProject.instance().transformContext(),
    options
)
```

But same result...
Can anyone tells me how to export in GPKG using a PyQGIS method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make use of the `includeZ` parameter of `QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions` you also need to specify the `overrideGeometryType`
parameter. Otherwise `includeZ` does not seem to be taking any effect.

I quote the API documentation for [`includeZ`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorFileWriter_1_1SaveVectorOptions.html#a8eff502826349cf2c9ec34536c897e1b):

> Sets to true to include z dimension in output. This option is only valid if overrideGeometryType is set.

Therefore your script can be adapted in the following way:

```
options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
options.driverName = "GPKG"
options.includeZ = True
options.overrideGeometryType = QgsWkbTypes.PointZ
options.layerName = 'test'
options.actionOnExistingFile = QgsVectorFileWriter.CreateOrOverwriteLayer

QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV3(
    vl,
    r"D:\test.gpkg",
    QgsProject.instance().transformContext(),
    options)

# load exported layer and check for z value:
layer = QgsVectorLayer(r"D:\test.gpkg|layername=test", "Points", "ogr")
for feat in layer.getFeatures():
    print(feat.geometry().constGet().z())
```

For simplicity I just used point geometries in my example.
If you have a different geometry type you of course need to change `overrideGeometryType` to `MultiPointZ`, `LineStringZ`, `PolygonZ`, `MultiSurfaceZ` etc.

Comment: Working good thank you very much!